# Jasmine spyOnevent undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

`spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#BackYoyButton', 'click');
        $('#BackYoyButton').trigger( "click" );
        expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn($('#BackYoyButton'));
        expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();`

I am trying to implement a test case for Angular JS with the help of jasmine . But when I tried to mock the buton click using spyOnEvent , it doesnt work

ReferenceError: spyOnEvent is not defined

Tried including jasmine-jquery too. But shows same error. Please help . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function before triggering the event:

```
it ('spy on button', function () {
    spyEvent = spyOnEvent($('#BackYoyButton'), 'click');
    $('#BackYoyButton').click();
    expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn($('#BackYoyButton'));
    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
});
```